# Which TextAppearance style matches the text below app launcher icons?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to create a 1x1 widget that looks similar to app launcher icons on the device lock screen.

This works fine except that the text style doesn't match the style used by other app launcher icons.

Which TextAppearance style is used for Launcher icons style?

Thanks

Comment: That would vary by launcher. There are hundreds of these, both pre-installed and user-installed.

Comment: There's no default one I can use that would at least match Google default launcher?

Comment: There is no single "Google default launcher". Devices usually come with their own launcher implementations, created by the device manufacturer.